# Issue with creating an image with PHP GD `imagecreatefromstring` function

Tags: php, curl, php-gd

I have a simple service that generates a PNG image of any text, using the parameters passed via a URL. One of the parameters is the text itself, the rest are things like 'font', 'color', 'font weight' etc.

An example of such a URL is:
http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php?params=Verdana%7C18%7Cbold%7Cnormal%7Ccenter%7C%23cc0000%7Cunderline&text=Hello%20world!

which generates the following PNG:

[image: original]

In another script, I'm using cURL to retrieve such a resource generated by this service, which I then convert to an image using `imagecreatefromstring()`, because I need to operate on it - things like rotating and scaling -, then to merge it with some other images.
For this I use the following code:

```
function getImage($url){
            $ch = curl_init ($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
            $resource = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

            return $resource;
    }


    $url = "http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php?params=Verdana%7C18%7Cbold%7Cnormal%7Ccenter%7C%23cc0000%7Cunderline&text=Hello%20world!";

    $string = getImage($url);
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);

    // Send the image to the client
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=mytext.png");
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
```

This same code is available **[here](http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/test.php)**, where you can see the output.
The problem is that the code above outputs some strange PNG, where all the letters are filled rectangles, like in the example bellow:

[image: sample result]

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

One other curious thing is that if I replace a URL to a text-image with, for instance, a link to a QR code generated with the Google Charts tool (e.g. [QR code](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=70&chl=http://cakemyface.co.uk&choe=UTF-8&chld=L)), the result is what it's supposed to be...

Comment: When I follow the example url (the first one) it's just a 10x10px white image?

Comment: I corrected the link, please try again.

Comment: Might it be a transparency issue? Try playing around with imagecolortransparent in text.php

Comment: @gogowitsch My thoughts exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little playing about I discovered the issue and the solution!

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('http://picselbocs.com/projects/cakemyface/text.php?params=Verdana|18|bold|normal|center|%23cc0000|underline&text=Hello%20world!'));
imagesavealpha($image, TRUE); // this is the fix
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($image);
```

The way I create my image is just a quick way without using curl, it seems the image needs it's alpha channels saving.